# Unable to get updated values of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a click event to a button that finds HTML elements by class and then adds each of them to an object with their name attribute as property name and the value attribute as the value.

```
$(function(){
  $('#saveButton').click(function() {
    let data = {};

    for (elem of $('.className')) {
      data[elem.getAttribute('name')] = elem.getAttribute('value');
    }

   console.log(data);
  });
});
```

This, however, only ever gives me the initial values of the elements. If I change the values (they are input fields) and the event is triggered again, it does not find the updated values. What's more confusing to me is that if I move `console.log(data);` right under the definition of `data`, the object already has properties and values, even when triggering the event the very first time. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code for what you are trying to do

```
 $('#saveButton').click(function() {
    var data = [];

$('.className').each(function(i, obj) {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

   console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much. I wasn't aware or jQuery.each(). But why did it not work the way I tried? I just want to understand what I did wrong.